# Working with very big data faster in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, file-io, vectorization, plaintext

I have to deal with very big data (Point clouds generally more than 30 000 000 points) using Matlab. I can read ascii data using `textscan` function. After reading, I need to detect invalid data (points with `0,0,0` coordinates) and then I need to do some mathematical operations on each point or each line in the data. In my way, first I read data with `textscan` and then I assign this data to a matrix. Secondly, I use `for` loops for detecting invalid points and doing some mathematical operations on each point or line in the data. A sample of my code is shown as below. According to profile tool of Matlab `textscan` takes 37% and line

```
transformed_list((i:i),(1:4)) = coordinate_list((i:i),(1:4))*t_matrix;
```

takes 35% of all computation time.

I tried it with another point cloud (stores around 5 500 000) and profile tool reported same results. Is there a way of avoiding `for` loops, or is there another way of speeding up this computation?

```
fileID = fopen('C:\Users\Mustafa\Desktop\ptx_all_data\dede5.ptx');             
original_data = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f', 'delimiter',' ');
fclose(fileID);
column = original_data{1}(1);
row = original_data{1}(2);
t_matrix = [original_data{1}(7) original_data{2}(7) original_data{3}(7) original_data{4}(7)
    original_data{1}(8) original_data{2}(8) original_data{3}(8) original_data{4}(8)
    original_data{1}(9) original_data{2}(9) original_data{3}(9) original_data{4}(9)
    original_data{1}(10) original_data{2}(10) original_data{3}(10) original_data{4}(10)];
coordinate_list(:,1) = original_data{1}(11:length(original_data{1}));
coordinate_list(:,2) = original_data{2}(11:length(original_data{2}));
coordinate_list(:,3) = original_data{3}(11:length(original_data{3}));
coordinate_list(:,4) = 0;
coordinate_list(:,5) = original_data{4}(11:length(original_data{4}));

transformed_list = zeros(length(coordinate_list),5);
for i = 1:length(coordinate_list)
    if coordinate_list(i,1) == 0 && coordinate_list(i,2) == 0 && coordinate_list(i,3) == 0
        transformed_list(i,:) = NaN;
    else
        %transformed_list(i,:) = coordinate_list(i,:)*t_matrix;
        transformed_list((i:i),(1:4)) = coordinate_list((i:i),(1:4))*t_matrix;
        transformed_list(i,5) = coordinate_list(i,5);
    end
    %i
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to speed up the data import or the processing? Importing 30,000,000 points is obviously going to take a significant chunk of time, I'm not sure why this is the concerning part.

Comment: _"avoiding `for` loops"_ usually means vectorizing, and vectorizing a process on such a large matrix will need a lot of memory. If you don't have enough memory for that, your MATLAB going to hung like forever... So, I'm not sure you really want to avoid the `for` loop.

Comment: I am interested in speeding up both data import and processing if possible. I am working with a work station and I will try some vectorizing.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops with conditional statements like those will take ages to run. But what Matlab lacks in loop speed it makes up with vectorization and indexing.

Let's try some logical indexing like this to solve the first step:

```
coordinate_list(coordinate_list(:,1) == 0 .* ...
                coordinate_list(:,2) == 0 .* ...
                coordinate_list(:,3) == 0)=nan;
```

And then vectorize the second statement:

```
transformed_list(:,(1:4)) = coordinate_list(:,(1:4))*t_matrix;
```

As EBH mentioned above this might be a bit heavy on your RAM. If it's more than your computer can handle asks yourself if the coordinates really have to be doubles, maybe single precision will do. If that still doesn't do, try slicing the vector and performing the operation in parts.

---

Small example to give you an idea because I had a 2million element point cloud around here:

In R2015a

```
transformed_list = zeros(length(coordinate_list),5);

tic
for i = 1:length(coordinate_list)
    if coordinate_list(i,1) == 0 && coordinate_list(i,2) == 0 && coordinate_list(i,3) == 0
        transformed_list(i,:) = NaN;
    else
        %transformed_list(i,:) = coordinate_list(i,:)*t_matrix;
        transformed_list((i:i),(1:3)) = coordinate_list((i:i),(1:3))*t_matrix;
        transformed_list(i,5) = 1;
    end
    %i
end
toc
```

Returns `Elapsed time is 10.928142 seconds.`

```
transformed_list=coordinate_list;
tic 

coordinate_list(coordinate_list(:,1) == 0 .* ...
                coordinate_list(:,2) == 0 .* ...
                coordinate_list(:,3) == 0)=nan;

transformed_list(:,(1:3)) = coordinate_list(:,(1:3))*t_matrix;


toc
```

Returns `Elapsed time is 0.101696 seconds.`

Comment: It's helpful to include version numbers when providing benchmarks. While it's hard to beat the performance of vectorized operations, MATLAB's loops *are* getting faster as the engine improves.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I will try these suggestions and let you know when I am done with coding.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than read the whole file,  you'd be better off using a loop with
`fscanf(fileID, '%f', 7)`
and processing input as you read it.

Comment: Do you have a benchmark to back up this assertion or are you just going to let it sit on its own?